# confused with attr to use with mouseover() and mouseout()(image swap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, attr

I am using `jQuery` to swap between images on and off hover. Here is my code.
**HTML**

```
<img class="commentImg" src="images/comments.png" data-swap="images/comment_hover.png" alt="">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".commentImg").hover(function() {
     var swap = $(this).attr("data-swap");
     $(this).attr('src', swap);
},
function() {
     var swap = $(this).attr("data-swap");
     $(this).removeAttr(swap);
 });
```

the `mouseover` works fine, but the `mouseout` doesn't. Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 3):

You need to store it

```js
//store current src in a attribute
$(".commentImg").attr('data-src', function() {
  return $(this).attr('src');
})
$(".commentImg").hover(function() {
  var swap = $(this).attr("data-swap");
  $(this).attr('src', swap);
}, function() {
  var src = $(this).attr("data-src");
  $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="commentImg" src="//placehold.it/64/ff0000" data-swap="//placehold.it/64/ff00ff" />
<img class="commentImg" src="//placehold.it/64/00ff00" data-swap="//placehold.it/64/ffff00" />
<img class="commentImg" src="//placehold.it/64/0000ff" data-swap="//placehold.it/64/00ffff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution which do accomplish the task and is also useful if you have many images. Here is the code. Might help someone out there,

**HTML**

```
  <div class="large-8 columns commentWrap">
     <img class="commentImg" src="images/comments.png" data-swap="images/comment_hover.png" alt="">
     <p class="inline_cmt">Comments (3)</p>
   </div>
   <div class="large-2 columns inline_rply">
     <img class="replyImg" src="images/reply.png" data-swap="images/reply_hover.png" alt="">
     <p class="dash_reply">Reply</p>
   </div>
   <div class="large-2 columns reportWrap">
      <img class="reportImg" src="images/report.png" data-swap="images/report_hover.png" alt="">
      <p class="inline_rep">Report</p>
   </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var sourceSwap = function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var newSource = $this.data('swap');
  $this.data('swap', $this.attr('src'));
  $this.attr('src', newSource);
  }

$('.commentImg').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
$('.replyImg').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
$('.reportImg').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
```